# When to use "A" before a proper noun?

Tags: grammar, nouns, articles, indefinite-articles

I wonder if we can put "A" before a proper noun. Here's an example I found on Google:

> As **a Vietnam veteran** I remembered that it was 16 years after my tour in Vietnam.

I wish to know why the author use "A" before "Vietnam." Thanks.

Comment: He is referring to himself as one of (many) other Vietnam veterans. "a"/"an" are indefinite articles. Please see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/when-should-i-use-a-vs-an

Comment: The first word in "Vietnam veteran" is what some call a noun adjunct or an [attributive noun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/346290/attributive-noun-vs-compound-noun). It acts like an adjective

Comment: @Mitch Quite right. I got ahead of myself:$

Comment: No prob. comments deleted

Comment: He could equally have said 'a veteran of the Vietnam war'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case **Vietnam** is descriptive, sometimes called  '[a restrictive appositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition)' or, better, a 'noun adjunct.'(thanks Mari-Lou A) which includes appositives and attributives.

Here are some other examples:

> A **George I** Penny.
>   An **Easter Island** statue.
>   [A **Burns** supper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burns_supper) with a piper and haggis.

It is better to think of the **"A"** going with **"veteran"** and the descriptor coming in between the two.

Comment: I think you intended to say *attribution*, not *apposition*; it's the difference between *the movie theater* and *the movie Star Wars*.